# Why the censorship?

Tags: discussion

The censorship on this site is alarming!

My [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/9176/2384) to this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/what-is-the-black-stone-in-the-kaaba) was deleted.

All I did was point the MANY similarities between "islamic" fairy tails and ancient pagan rituals. No offence, insult, or abuse was intended or implied.

We need to be able to discuss these things out in the open.

I visit this site often enough that I caught this extreme censorship to other posters in the past.

So I ask, why the censorship?

Comment: Just saw this post. I asked similar question http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/794/should-answers-like-these-be-deleted-on-this-site

Comment: It thinkmwhat others want to tekk is that when someone ask a question here he/she is expecting an answer from an Islamic point of view. other than that.... Common sense says don't ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was hardly useful, and didn't even answer the question as far as I saw.  The one asking the question was asking why The Black stone is important, and what it is made of, and not about the similarities between what you call fairy tales and pagan rituals.  I deleted your answer because it doesn't answer the question put forth.

Answer (score 2):

The whole post looked like nothing more than speculation, and most of it just attacked a number of beliefs (that are held and respected by a large number of Muslims) about the black stone and the umrah in general, rather than answering the question itself.

We are not a site for polemic or discussion, we are a site for answering questions.  Posts that don't answer the question asked are liable to get deleted.

And posts which blatantly attack beliefs held by a large number of people (whether or not this offense was intended is irrelevant) are liable to be flagged as offensive.  Which this post was.  Hence it was deleted.

This is just the community deciding what it does and does not want in its site: It's not censorship, it's curation.

See also: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the answer but in general:

> the answers on this site should be based on Islamic perspectives and Islamic sources.

It is not appropriate to post answers based on non-Islamic sources, particularly those which are considered anti-Islamic and are likely to be considered offensive by Muslims.

It seems that your answer was such an answer so I think its deletion was appropriate.